# Efficient Algorithm for Box Triangle Collission Test

Tags: c#, algorithm, graphics, 3d

I have three vertices of a triangle i.e. (x1,y1,z1); (x2,y2,z2) and (x3,y3,z3).
The bounding box of my triangle is a cube of length = Maximum(xmax-xmin, ymax-ymin,zmax-zmin). xmax,xmin,....,zmin can be calculated by looping through all the vertices of the triangle.

Now,considering a particular resolution size(h), I divide my bounding box into grids.For example,if my bounding box is of length 10 and resolution is 1,No. of grids will be 1000(10*10*10).

Now,I want to find out all those grids(cubes) which are intersected by my Triangle as well as those cubes,which lie inside my triangle.

I am following the below approach:
-> Storing all the grids of my bounding box in a list (using 3 "for" loops for x,y,z.This involves huge memory wastage)
-> I am then looping through each grid coordinate in my list,checking out if the cube lies on my plane,if the cube lines on my plane,then I am checking if my grid is intersected by three edges of my  triangle (or) if my grid is located inside my triangle.

I am using the following algorithms for checking the intersection and inside criteria:

```
 bool IfLineIntersectsPoint(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        bool checkifIntersects = false;
        FindProjectedPointonPlane(x, y, z);
       //Px,Py and Pz are projected points on the plane
        if ((((Px - vertex1x) / a) == ((Py - vertex1y) / b)) && (((Px - vertex1x) / a) == ((Pz - vertex1z) / c)))
        {
            checkifIntersects = true;
        }
        return checkifIntersects;
    }

bool PointInTriangle(Vector3[] TriangleVectors, Vector3 P)
        {
            Vector3 A = TriangleVectors[0], B = TriangleVectors[1], C = TriangleVectors[2];
            if (SameSide(P, A, B, C) && SameSide(P, B, A, C) && SameSide(P, C, A, B))
            {
                Vector3 AB = Vector3.Subtract(A, B);
                Vector3 AC = Vector3.Subtract(A, C);
                Vector3 AP = Vector3.Subtract(A, P);
                Vector3 vc1 = Vector3.Cross(AB, AC);

                float magnitude1 = AB.Length();
                float magnitude2 = vc1.Length();
                Vector3 NormAP = new Vector3(AP.X / magnitude1, AP.Y / magnitude1, AP.Z / magnitude1);
                Vector3 NormVC1 = new Vector3(vc1.X / magnitude2, vc1.Y / magnitude2, vc1.Z / magnitude2);
                float ftw = Math.Abs(Vector3.Dot(NormAP, NormVC1));
                if (ftw <= 0.1f)
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

I would be really glad,if someone can suggest any changes in my algorithm and the above two functions,so as to minimize my computation time. Also,if I have some 8-9 triangles,Everytime,I am checking all these criteria for all 1000 grids.Can I get some subset(some 100-150 grids) of these 1000 grids and proceed?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) might work. Start with the gridcube that contains one of the triangle vertices. Then check each of the adjacent 26 gridcubes. For each of those that intersect the triangle, search the adjacent gridcubes (some of which have already been checked and can be ignored).

Comment: Could you please provide some pseudo code. Its not that easy for me to interpret it and implement it.

Comment: @user3386109: the problem is, if you try to find the grid cube,that contains  one of the triangle vertices,you get 8 cubes. Because,in 3-D, each 3D Point can lie common to 8 cubes.

Comment: Yes, it's true that there are 8 cubes to consider. But some will be outside of the bounding box, and can be ignored. Either way, nothing prevents you from starting a BFS with multiple cubes. In the pseudo code provided by wikipedia, the line `open_set.enqueue(start)` starts the search with one entry. Instead, you would enqueue as many entries as needed to start the search.